# Почему поддомен не доступен во внешней сети , на локальном сервере debian 10 + роутер Wive-NG-MT?

Tags: linux, debian, ip, роутер

Есть основной **домен.ru**, на отдельной вдс с сайтом
есть белый ип **xx.xxx.xx.xxx** + локальный debian booster, на котором я хочу поднять поддомен **test.домен.ru**

что я делаю :

**/etc/network/interface**

```
auto lo
iface enp3s0 inet static
address 192.168.1.36
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.0
gateway 10.0.0.100
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4.4
```

..перенаправляю трафик ..?

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dst xx.xxx.xx.xxx --dporpt 80 -j DNAT -to-destination 192.168.1.36:80

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dst xx.xxx.xx.xxx --dporpt 80 -j SNAT -to-source xx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
#nameserver 192.168.1.36
domain **test.домен.ru**
```

=========================================

```
systemctl restart networking.service
```

также указал А запись **xx.xxx.xx.xxx**  ( у хостера где расположен основной **домен.ru** )

в итоге после всего картина такая

- localhost - открывается welcome deb.html
- 192.168.1.36 - открывается welcome deb.html
- **xx.xxx.xx.xxx**   - редиректит на главную стр. роутера ( как 192.168.1.1)
- **test.домен.ru**  - также редиректит на роутер ( из вне доступа нет)

Отключал, фаервол, сбрасывал iptables, результат +- одинаковый.

Как мне определить в чем проблема?

на всякий случай некоторые настройки роутера

тут пробовал пробросить порты( с галкой и без,  и вообще выкл)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не понятно зачем вы перенаправляете трафик на debian? Он же за роутером? Значит роутер и должен на него трафик слать, никакие правила iptables там не нужны. Проблема явно в правилах роутера.

Comment: без правил iptables также не работает

Comment: да потому что они не нужны. вы читали комментарий вообще? что за роутер?

Comment: https://wi-cat.ru/wive-ng-mt-changelog/

Comment: я уже [давно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/929873/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-bitrix-vm-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)  решал этот вопрос, получилось через манипуляции port forwarding, правда в локальной сети все равно редиректилось на роутер, а с  внешней было норм.мб прошивка?

Comment: @ЕгорRmd, что-то не вижу, где ты настроил, где находится  поддомен `test.домен.ru`...  вообще говоря, перенаправление портов тут скорей всего (см. дальше) излишне... тебе было бы достаточно просто настроить DNS...  самое простое — на стороне провайдера, у которого арендуешь `домен.ru` перенаправить поддомен на ip своего vds. Если регистратор такой услуги не предоставляет или это ещё почему-то нельзя сделать, то придётся полноценный dns сервер подымать у себя и на него уже с роутера перенаправить 53-е порты... хотя может и сам роутер умеет dns'ом работать...

Comment: А вот если стоит задача извратиться, скрыть существование vds и пустить весь трафик через роутер и свой компьютер, то на беглый взгляд правила перенаправления правильные...  но dns всё равно настроить придётся, чтоб обозначить, где находится поддомен `test`.